# Regex find & replace data cleaning

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a csv I would like to clean up in Notepad++ with regex and the find and replace tool.

I want to do something like: find ^"(\d+).* and replace with $1 so that

```
"25110716
"
```

and

```
"27155790
AirBnB-16261519-PBH2ED"
```

end up 25110716 and 27155790. These are the first entry in every row.

Right now using find ^"(\d+).* and replace with $1 in NPP finds the first entry in every row and returns it the same but missing the first quotation mark. I would like everything that isn't the first numbers removed, i.e. all quotation marks, and the linebreak & everything on the following line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this in the following way ...

- ***Find what :*** `(?m)^"(\d+)\n.*?(?=,|$)`
- ***Replace with :*** `$1`

see **[regex demo / explanation](https://regex101.com/r/6C14xM/2)**

Comment: This helps but it is getting rid of everything that follows the first matching group. Following the quotation marks I want to get rid of are commas (because it's csv), so I'd like a regex find that ends before that comma

Comment: perfect, thank you. Do you happen to have a good resource for learning how to come up with such crazy regexs?